# How to set order position in css?

Tags: css, reactjs

So i try to use some css animated background. It look like this:
[image]

The particle hovers above the menu list (for now it just "test"). My particle code is in css:

```
.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgb(17, 218, 94, 0.4);
  animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}
```

I got this particle effect from some website. As you can see it's just manually assign animation to `<li>`. I use React, my react code look like this:

```
return (
    <div className="area w-screen">
      <div className=" bg-white px-3 py-5">
        <nav className="flex justify-between px-10 ">
          <ul className=" flex items-center ">
            <li>
              <div className=" text-stone-800 font-bold text-xl px-5">
                LogoGoesEre
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className=" text-zinc-900" href="">
                Dashboard
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="px-3">
              <a className=" text-zinc-900" href="">
                Quiz
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">
            <button className=" bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-700 rounded-xl px-3 py-2 text-white">
              Logout
            </button>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className=" bg-slate-50 w-1/3 h-1/2 p-5 m-10">
        <h1>text</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul className="circles">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

How to set the particle so it appear bellow my other item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` of a positioned element and any flex elements that are descended from it is determined by the `z-index` CSS attribute.
Elements with bigger `z-index` overlap smaller ones.

Example:

```
.ClassName {
z-index: 2;
}

.ClassName2 {
z-index: 1;
}
```

In this case `.ClassName` has a higher `z-index` then the `ClassName2` element, so it would be visible on top of `.ClassName2` element.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `z-index` to the menu so it will stack on top of the position absolute circles.
As long as the `z-index` of the me nu is higher than the one of the background you should be fine.